# HTML form action method="POST" or method="post"?

Tags: html

Is there any difference in using non-capticalized "post" or capitalized "POST" in `<form>` action method? I just want to strictly follow W3C HTML specification.

This is no difference when running in modern browsers, though.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the [w3c docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-method) for forms:

> Possible (case-insensitive) values are "get" (the default) and "post".

Answer (score 9):

No difference! I always use lower case.

Comment: Why did I get a down vote on this yesterday?  Seems strange to go down vote a random 3 year old answer that isn't incorrect...

Comment: I got an up-vote on this 4 year old answer today, and I read this comment which reminded me... <em>Why</em> did someone down vote this? I'm so curious.  Down votes to an answer that isn't wrong, with no feedback, are the worst (maybe he didn't like my opinion of always using lower case).

Comment: Hate it when people down vote base on personal opinions, and not on when an answer is wrong. Here's a small up vote consolation.

Comment: Maybe i can answer two years later.  My best guess is that you didn't have any proof.  A link to the documentation would have made this answer undeniable.

Answer (score 7):

from http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html

Many strings in the HTML syntax (e.g. the names of elements and their attributes) are case-insensitive, but only for characters in the ranges U+0041 to U+005A (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A to LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z) and U+0061 to U+007A (LATIN SMALL LETTER A to LATIN SMALL LETTER Z). For convenience, in this section this is just referred to as "case-insensitive".